# Counting appearance of an element in many lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have several lists:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
l2 = [1,3,5,7]
l3 = [4,5,1,8,2]
l4 = [1,2,6,7]
l5 = [5,7,8]
```

and I want to count number of appearance of every element, so the output should be

```
element 1 appears in 3 lists
element 2 in 3
element 3 in 2
element 4 in 2
element 5 in 4
...
```

Can I do that using any built in function or a smart idea? Because I can do that using loops but it seems to be very disruptive idea.

Comment: So where *is* your "disruptive" loop-based implementation? What are *your* smart ideas? Have you read through the [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) you mention? Have you, in fact, put *any* effort into this yourself?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the OP said that "he can do it using loops", but chose not to. He's asking for an approach. While it may seem to be a problem relating to inexperience, it's also one of imagination. Not everyone is equipped similarly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd combine [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> all_lists = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> all_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(all_lists))
>>> for k, v in all_counts.items():
...     print('element', k, 'appears in', v, 'lists')
...     
element 1 appears in 4 lists
element 2 appears in 3 lists
element 3 appears in 2 lists
element 4 appears in 2 lists
element 5 appears in 4 lists
element 6 appears in 2 lists
element 7 appears in 4 lists
element 8 appears in 3 lists
```

(where you might want to toss in a `sorted` in there if you want to guarantee the output order is ascending.)

If @jonrsharpe is right, and you need to handle the case where an element can occur multiple times in a single list (right now it's really "element 1 occurs 4 *times*", not in 4 lists), you can toss a `set` in there:

```
all_counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(set, all_lists)))
```

so that no matter how many times an element occurs in a list, it only counts for 1.

Comment: cool idea(+1) :) that's a neat approach I wouldnt have thought of

Comment: This may give the wrong answer if e.g. `1` appears twice in the same list, depending on what output the OP needs

Comment: @DSM Thanks for your answer! So many new things I can learn from this example. In my problem I don't need to carry on a scenario when the same element appears many times in one list, but I this example is also very good for other functions which I want to create.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers = set(l1+l2+l3+l4+l5)
for n in numbers:
    print "%d in %d lists"%(n,sum(n in l for l in [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5]) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use defaultdict to go over the lists only once -

```
counter = defaultdict(int)
for list_ in [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5]:
    for value in list_:
        counter[value] += 1
for key in sorted(counter.keys()):
    print('Value {} appears in {} lists'.format(key, counter[key]))
```

This gives the following output -

```
Value 1 appears in 4 lists
Value 2 appears in 3 lists
Value 3 appears in 2 lists
Value 4 appears in 2 lists
Value 5 appears in 4 lists
Value 6 appears in 2 lists
Value 7 appears in 4 lists
Value 8 appears in 3 lists
```

Comment: this is really the same as  DSM's answer below ... but +1 since both of these have better overall complexity than mine

Comment: I think DSM's answer is way cooler than mine. :) I haven't worked with `collections.Counter` before.